# Where is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to publish junit.xml test results in an Azure DevOps pipeline but the task isn't finding it.

What would the path be from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

to the generated `junit.xml` after running an `npm test` task?

[image: Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could use this glob pattern to scan all the folders: `**/junit.xml`.

that being said `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. so, root of the repo, effectively.

Comment: Typically after about an hour I figured it out just before the answer:  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/InspectionWeb/ClientApp/src

Comment: Thanks for the glob pattern too :)

Answer (score 2):

I personally find these commands very useful when working out where in the hierarchy you are:

```
    - powershell: "Write-Output 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'"
    - script: dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    - script: dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xxx/yyy
```

Then you can inspect these tasks and see what the output is...